# rabbitMQ in WCF project returns error ,but it works in a same console project in same PC

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, console-application, .net-framework-version

I am trying to publish a message from a wcf(4.5.2 .net framework ) project as you can see :

```
public Int64 FindChargeByOrganization(string id)
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", UserName = "symfa", Password = "123qweQWE@" };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "symfa_queue",
                                     durable: false,
                                     exclusive: false,
                                     autoDelete: false,
                                     arguments: null);

                string message = "Hello World!";
                var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                                     routingKey: "symfa_queue",
                                     basicProperties: null,
                                     body: body);
             
            }

            return 1;
        }
```

And when I call the URL i get this error :

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'
IOException: connection.start was never received, likely due to a network timeout
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.StartAndTune()
    RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.Open(bool)
    RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.Connection(RabbitMQ.Client.IConnectionFactory, bool, RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.IFrameHandler, string)
    RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.IFrameHandler)
    RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(RabbitMQ.Client.IEndpointResolver)
    RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(RabbitMQ.Client.IEndpointResolver, string)
```

[image]
But when I call this code with a console application with netframework 4.5.2 It works .

[image]

Comment: So you are running under IIS Express (based on the screenshot)?

Comment: @mjwills Yes...

Comment: Have you tried running it in IIS rather than IIS Express?

Comment: @mjwills I check it. same error